# Problem S3 AWS Get list of bject

Tags: aws

I am trying to get the list of objects exists in my bucket but I am getting

"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

What I doing wrong here?

```
String S3SECRET = 'mysecretkey';
String S3BUCKET = 'mybucket';
String S3KEY = 'mykey';
String S3HOST = 's3.amazonaws.com';
String ENDPOINT = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/' + S3BUCKET;
String dateString =Datetime.now().formatGmt('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z');
String stringToSign = 'GET\n'                           // HTTP-Verb
                            + '\n' 
                            + '\n'
                            + dateString + '\n';

Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1', Blob.valueof(stringToSign),Blob.valueof(S3SECRET));
String signedString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);

HttpRequest con = new HttpRequest();

con.setHeader('Authorization','AWS ' + CustomSettings.S3Key+':' + signedString);
con.setHeader('Host', S3BUCKET + '.' + S3HOST);
con.setHeader('Date', dateString);
con.setMethod('GET');
con.setEndPoint(ENDPOINT);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(con);


Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
String resBody = res.getBody();
System.debug(Logginglevel.WARN, 'GET STATUS CODE:' + statusCode + 'RES.GETBODY: ' + resBody + ' RES.GETSTATUS: ' + res.getStatus() + ' CON.GETENDPT: ' + con.getEndPoint())
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake I had username and bucket confused. It is now working :)